# How to do pagination on server side with ngPrime tables in Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

I could not find any documentation on it. 
The ngPrime has all the features required for my project standpoint, but I want to be sure that ngPrime table supports server side pagination as it is a required feature.

Comment: yes, [check this](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy), Cheers!!